# String to Bluetooth SPP R200 format routine for Android

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I am trying to print a message to a Bluetooth connected printer via SPP R200 protocol though my Android phone. I have paired, connected with the device. But the language the printer speaks is not the regular strings.

As far as I understand, the SPP R200 is a standard format but scary format as I feel it.

Because it is a standard format, is any standard routine / function/ method known that will convert the normal Java string to the spp r200 format? Any open source implementation or sample codes are welcome.

Thanks for the stackoverflow community in advance because I know somebody is always there to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is read [manual](http://www.bixolon.com/com_updata/bixolon_download/SPP-R200%20Command%20Manual_English_Rev_1_00%282%29.pdf) and then send byte arrays not string to printer

fx. Printing code bar(CODE39, text: "aa1234"):

```
{GS,   len("aa1234"), 4/* CODE39*/, (byte)'a', (byte)'a', (byte)'1', (byte)'2', (byte)'3', (byte)'4', 0/*NUL*/}

{0x1d, 0x06,          0x04,          0x61,      0x61,      0x31,      0x32,      0x33,      0x34,     0x00}
```

for getting bytes from string use:

```
"my string".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: I am currently struggling with sendimg bitmaps - I even decompiled the SDK and I am imitating the Bitmap printing behaviour, but it only prints two small dots - more of a mistake than a success I am afraid... However thanks for the manual reference! I only had the SDK Api which is ... pretty poor.